# Simple Java TextEditor program not working

Tags: java

So for I was suppose to create a text-editor program where editing is done via a command which, in turn, is executed by the corresponding method. I was suppose to utilize this text-editor program with two files a) A novel .txt file such as  tale of two cities and b) a file that contains a list of properly spelled words as for reference for the spellcheck methods
I was to utilized the following:

1. boolean Find (String x) // Looks for a word "x" in the file and returns true if found or false otherwise.
2. boolean FindReplace (String x, String y) // looks for the first occurrence of word "x" in the file and replaces it with word "y" if found returning true, false otherwise.
3. boolean FindInsert (String x, String y)  // looks for the first occurrence of word "x" in the file and then insert "y" right after "x", if x is found, returning true, false otherwise.
4. boolean Delete (String x) // looks for the first occurrence of word "x" in the file and deletes it from the file, returning true if x is found, returning false otherwise.
5. String spellCheck ()  // finds the first occurrence of spelling error and returns the misspelled word. If no word is misspelled returns "Spell Check Passed".
6. void spellCheckAll() // find all misspelled words and output them to the screen.
7. void save() // saves file with the changes made.
8. void print() // saves file with the changes and outputs the contents of the file to the screen.
9. void quit() should save() the file and exit.

   ### 10. boolean FindReplaceAll (String x, String y) // looks for all occurrences of word "x" in the file and replace each with word "y" if found returning true, false otherwise.

This is the code I have so far. It compiles. However, when I try to object test any of methods they won't work. For example, my method to find the occurrence of a string within a .txt file will always return false I'm assuming there are some issues either a) my boolean method loops b) there's some issues with the creation of my linked list that I used for my file that's being read in and/or my hash map that I used for my dictionary/reference file. I'm stumped.

```
package FileEditor;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class FileEditor {
    static LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    public FileEditor() {
        super();
    }

    public static void readNovelFile() {

        String content = new String();
        File file = new File("2city10.txt");

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                content = sc.nextLine();
                list.add(content);

            }
            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
            fnf.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\nProgram terminated Safely...");
        }

    }


    public static boolean findText(String x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String text = list.get(i);
            if (text.contains(x) || text.equals(x)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void findAndReplace(String x, String y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String text = list.get(i);
            if (text.contains(x) || text.equals(x)) {
                text = text.replaceAll(x, y);
                list.remove(i);
                list.add(i, text);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void findAndInsert(String x, String y) {
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String text = list.get(i);
            if (text.contains(x) || text.equals(x)) {
                if (flag == false)
                    text = text.replace(x, x + " " + y);
                list.remove(i);
                list.add(i, text);
            }
            flag = true;
        }

    }

    public static void delete(String x) {
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String text = list.get(i);
            if (text.contains(x) || text.equals(x)) {
                if (flag == false)
                    text = text.replace(x, "");
                list.remove(i);
                list.add(i, text);
            }
            flag = true;
        }

    }


    public static HashSet<String> readWords(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        // Use any characters other than a-z or A-Z as delimiters
        in.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]+");
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            words.add(in.next().toLowerCase());
        }
        return words;
    }

    public static void spellCheck() {
        // Read the dictionary and the document

        Set<String> dictionaryWords = null;
        Set<String> documentWords = null;
        boolean flag = false;
        try {
            dictionaryWords = readWords("EnglishWordList.txt");
            documentWords = readWords("2city10.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }


        // Print all words that are in the document but not the dictionary

        for (String word : documentWords) {
            if (!dictionaryWords.contains(word) && flag == false) {
                System.out.println(word);
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void spellCheckAll() {
        // Read the dictionary and the document

        Set<String> dictionaryWords = null;
        Set<String> documentWords = null;
        try {
            dictionaryWords = readWords("EnglishWordList.txt");
            documentWords = readWords("2city10.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }


        // Print all words that are in the document but not the dictionary

        for (String word : documentWords) {
            if (!dictionaryWords.contains(word)) {
                System.out.println("Misspelled words :" + word);

            }
        }
    }

    public static void saveFile() {
        BufferedWriter out;
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("2city10.txt"));

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                out.write(list.get(i).toString());

                out.write('\n'); // add a new line
            }
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void printFile() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).toString());

            //out.write('\n'); // add a new line
        }

    }

    public static void menuList() {
        System.out.println("\n Enter the Choice ...");
        System.out.println("\n Enter 1 to Find ");
        System.out.println("\n Enter 2 to FindReplace  ");
        System.out.println("\n Enter 3 to FindInsert  ");
        System.out.println("\n Enter 4 to Delete  ");
        System.out.println("\n Enter 5 to spellCheck  ");
        System.out.println("\n Enter 6 to spellCheckAll  ");
        System.out.println("\n Enter 7 to save  ");
        System.out.println("\n Enter 8 to print  ");
        System.out.println("\n Enter 9 to quit  ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        readNovelFile();
        int choice = 0;
        menuList();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        choice = scanner.nextInt();
        while (true) {
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                {
                    String input = "";
                    System.out.println("\nEnter the string to Find ...");
                    Scanner textscan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    input = textscan.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("The String entered exists :" +
                                       findText(input));
                    menuList();
                    choice = scanner.nextInt();
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                String find = "";
                String replace = "";
                System.out.println("\nEnter the string to Find ...");
                Scanner findScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                find = findScan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\nEnter the string to Replace ...");
                Scanner replaceScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                replace = replaceScan.nextLine();
                findAndReplace(find, replace);
                menuList();
                choice = scanner.nextInt();
                break;
            case 3:
                String findStr = "";
                String insStr = "";
                System.out.println("\nEnter the string to Find ...");
                Scanner findStrScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                findStr = findStrScan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\nEnter the string to Insert ...");
                Scanner InsertStrScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                insStr = InsertStrScan.nextLine();
                findAndInsert(findStr, insStr);
                menuList();
                choice = scanner.nextInt();
                break;
            case 4:
                String delete = "";
                System.out.println("\nEnter the string to Delete ...");
                Scanner deleteScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                delete = deleteScan.nextLine();
                delete(delete);
                menuList();
                choice = scanner.nextInt();
                break;

            case 5:
                System.out.println("\nSpell checking for first occurence ....");
                spellCheck();
                menuList();
                choice = scanner.nextInt();
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("\nSpell checking for All  occurences ....");
                spellCheckAll();
                menuList();
                choice = scanner.nextInt();
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("\nSaving the File ....");
                saveFile();
                menuList();
                choice = scanner.nextInt();
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("\nSaving and Printing the File ....");
                saveFile();
                printFile();
                menuList();
                choice = scanner.nextInt();
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println("\nEXIT MENU ....");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To see if a string contains another string, look for the string but using a substring test, rather than contains. `b = text.indexOf(x)  <= 0;` . IndexOf will return -1 if the string you're checking for isn't found, or a number from zero upward it it is, telling you what character your test string starts on.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your program in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

For your `findText` always returning false....

```
public static boolean findText(String x) {
    boolean found;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String text = list.get(i);
        if (text.contains(x)) { // You also dont need that "equals()" here
            found=true;
            break; // Break loop if text found
        } else {
            found=false;
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

But as mentioned in comments, better way is this:

```
public static boolean findText(String x) {
    boolean found;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if(list.get(i).indexOf(x) >= 0){
          found =  true;
          break;
        }
        else
          found = false
    }
  return found;
}
```

Another way to do this without manually involving loops is:

```
public static boolean findText(String x) {
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, x);
    if(index >= 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```